# Eclipse: IProcess output on console

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, process, eclipse-plugin

I have a problem when I try to write to the console.

In the plugin project i have developed a custom build which could be called through the menus using commands i developed. Originally the build was called inside the `launch` method of my class which implements ILaunchConfigurationDelegate.

```
...
        String[] commandLine = (String[]) compilerArgs.toArray(new String[compilerArgs.size()]);
        Process compilerProcess = DebugPlugin.exec(commandLine, new File(project.getLocation().toString()));

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map processAttributes = new HashMap();
        processAttributes.put(IProcess.ATTR_PROCESS_TYPE, "XVR");
        IProcess dbgProcess = DebugPlugin.newProcess(launch, compilerProcess, "XVR Compiler", processAttributes);

        try {
            compilerProcess.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(compilerProcess.exitValue() != 0) return false;
        launch.removeProcess(dbgProcess);
```

When a build was performed, the output of the process is printed on the console and parsed with a class which implements IConsoleLineTracker to highlights the errors.

I moved the build method outside the class which implements ILaunchConfigurationDelegate and the console is not printed anymore. The only difference between the two cases is how the object iLaunch is provided. The new build method follows

```
   ...
String[] commandLine = (String[]) compilerArgs.toArray(new String[compilerArgs.size()]);
    Process compilerProcess = DebugPlugin.exec(commandLine, new File(prj.getLocation().toString()));

    ILaunch xvrLaunch = XVRUtils.getXVRLaunch();
    Map<String, String> processAttributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    processAttributes.put(IProcess.ATTR_PROCESS_TYPE, "XVR");

    IProcess dbgProcess = DebugPlugin.newProcess(xvrLaunch, compilerProcess, "XVR Compiler", processAttributes);

    try {
        compilerProcess.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(compilerProcess.exitValue() != 0)
        return false;
    xvrLaunch.removeProcess(dbgProcess);
```

the launch is provided with the following function

```
public static ILaunch getXVRLaunh(){
    ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
    ILaunch[] launches = manager.getLaunches();
    if(launches.length > 0){
        for (ILaunch launch : launches) {
            ILaunchConfiguration conf = launch.getLaunchConfiguration();
            try {
                if(conf.getType().equals(manager.getLaunchConfigurationType(ApplicationLaunchConfigurationDelegate.XVR_LAUNCH_CONFIGURATION_ID)))
                    return launch;
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    ILaunchConfiguration config = getXVRLaunchConfiguration();
    Launch l = new Launch(config, "run, debug", null);
    l.setAttribute(DebugPlugin.ATTR_CAPTURE_OUTPUT, null);
    try {
        if (l.getSourceLocator() == null) {
            String type;
            type = config.getAttribute(ILaunchConfiguration.ATTR_SOURCE_LOCATOR_ID, (String)null);

            if (type == null) {
                type = config.getType().getSourceLocatorId();
            }
            if (type != null) {
                IPersistableSourceLocator locator = manager.newSourceLocator(type);
                String memento = config.getAttribute(ILaunchConfiguration.ATTR_SOURCE_LOCATOR_MEMENTO, (String)null);
                if (memento == null) {
                    locator.initializeDefaults(config);
                } else {
                    if(locator instanceof IPersistableSourceLocator2)
                        ((IPersistableSourceLocator2)locator).initializeFromMemento(memento, config);
                    else
                        locator.initializeFromMemento(memento);
                }
                l.setSourceLocator(locator);
            }
        }
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return l;
}
```

Why the process does not print on the console anymore?

thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions in your log?

Comment: Is your build() method called from (directly or indirectly) the class that implements ILaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch()?

Comment: Close vote. Nor required output is described neither a code that should produce output is exactly indicated.