# Inconsistent output to Eclipse Console View

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am invoking a compiler command but the compiler messages are not getting displayed in the Eclipse Console View consistently.

I have my launch() method implemented the same way as first code block of
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536446/eclipse-iprocess-output-on-console); I have the command-line string setup which I use to call DebugPlugin.exec() method. However, unlike the the author of the question above, my output Eclipse console is very inconsistent.  T

There is no activity in the console when I invoke the command and the console continues to display the "No console to display at this time." But after invoking the command numerous time and activating different consoles from the drop-down menu, the console occasionally does become active and message is displayed.

I am confused with how the eclipse is behaving and not sure how to resolve this issue. Any comment and/or recommendation would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

--
EDIT

To add some more info, running the external process using External Tools works fine.  I add the compiler process `c:\path\myprocess.exe` in `Locations` field and the file to compile in the `Arguments` field within the External Tools Configuration window.  When I run it, all the output is displayed fine. It just won't display when I run it programmatically through `LaunchConfigurationDelegate` class.

Comment: Another comment to this is that the only major difference between the external tools and my code is that the instance run by external tools is run on separate worker thread while my code runs in the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. The main change I've made is having my `MyLaunchConfigurationDelegate` extend `LaunchConfigurationDelegate` instead of just implementing `ILaunchConfigurationDelegate`.  When observed through the debugger, the launch() method went through similar code path as external process that was launched via External Tools when `MyLaunchConfigurationDelegate` extended `LaunchConfigurationDelegate`.

I guess it was lack of information on my part but I wasn't sure which part of the code was more important to share.

Another piece of code that was removed was:

```
IProcess dbgProcess = DebugPlugin.newProcess(launch, compilerProcess, "XVR Compiler", processAttributes);
...
launch.removeProcess(dbgProcess);
```

I've added it while attempting different approach in debugging this issue and it actually caused more issues by removing the debugProcess before it has chance to display output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try bringing the console to front programmatically see if it helps:

```
* Bring the console to front.
 */
public static void showConsole() {
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            IWorkbenchWindow window = CUIPlugin.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
            if (window != null) {
                IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
                if (page != null) {
                    IViewPart consoleView =
                            page.findView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW);
                    if (consoleView == null) {
                        IWorkbenchPart activePart = page.getActivePart();
                        try {
                            consoleView =
                                    page.showView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW);
                        } catch (PartInitException pie) {
                            CUIPlugin.log(pie);
                        }
                        // restore focus stolen by the creation of the
                        // console
                        page.activate(activePart);
                    } else {
                        boolean bringToTop = true;
                        if (bringToTop) {
                            page.bringToTop(consoleView);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a shot but the console returned by findView() is the consoleView with "No console to display at this time." title.  Perhaps, the output is not even being directed correctly to the console? Or, no console is being created? If I create my own console page, how do I direct my output from "DebugPlugin.exec()" to my console?